# Se puede escribir en un comboBox y que empiecen a aparecer disminuir los datos en el mismo, de modo que funcione como filtro?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, elementos

Para ser breve, digamos que tengo un comboBox con 1000 elementos entre los que puedo elegir y me gustaría saber, de ser posible, si cuando yo ingreso caracteres al mismo, pueden aparecer los elementos que concuerden con los caracteres que se ingresaron? Ejemplo: tengo países cargados y, si yo escribo "A", que empiecen a disminuir los elementos, de modo que me muestre solo los que comienzan con dicho caracter.
Pido disculpas si es una pregunta tonta o si no está lo suficientemente claro, la plataforma sigue siendo nueva para mí.
Gracias por leer mi duda :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no usas base de datos y todos tus valores están dentro de la ListItems de tu ComboBox puedes usar la propiedad `Autocomplete`

por ejemplo
usas `AutoCompleteMode` para determinar la manera en que buscaras en el comboBox, y usarias suggest para desplegar una lista auxiliar de lo que vayas tecleando

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
```

y al final determinas el origen de datos que seria

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Comment: Excelente! Muy precisa y completa tu respuesta. Te agradezco por tomarte el tiempo de responder! :D